# Rigacar/Rigify Tab gone

Tags: rigify

I once was able to see the rigacar tab with all the other tabs in my viewport (the ones by the navigation, that little sidebar that slides in and out with N, but it seems to be gone. Maybe after an update? Anyone else having this issue figure it out yet? It's not that I haven't enabled it in preferences, I've have had it enabled for a while now, it just seems to have disappeared and no option anywhere to enable it again. I'm trying to follow along with a car animation tutorial that uses rigacar and I cannot use mine for whatever reason even tho I can see some of the options in the property tabs underneath the outliner, but no rigacar tab. Im trying to get the wheels to move with the car on the path without having to animate the keyframes, I mean isn't that mostly the reason why we want to use rigacar anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Scripting tab or create a text editor window, from its dropdown menu select the text file named as your rig followed by _ui.py, then press the play button to execute the script.

[image]